# I am trying to split logic from Trigger to handler class with "Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void Error

Tags: trigger, after-trigger, event-handler

I am a starting SF developer and having issues with handler class.
This is my original trigger:

```
trigger OpportunityTrigger on Opportunity (after insert, after update, after delete) {    
    Map<Id, List<Opportunity>> acctIdOpptyListMap = new Map<Id, List<Opportunity>>();
    Set<Id> acctIds = new Set<Id>();
    List<Opportunity> opptyList = new List<Opportunity>();
    if(trigger.isUpdate || trigger.isInsert){
        for(Opportunity oppty : trigger.New){
            if(oppty.AccountId != null){
                acctIds.add(oppty.AccountId);
            }
        }    
    }
    if(trigger.isDelete){
        for(Opportunity oppty : trigger.old){
            if(oppty.AccountId != null){
                acctIds.add(oppty.AccountId);
            }
        }    
    }
    if(acctIds.size() > 0){
        opptyList = [SELECT Amount, AccountId FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId IN : acctIds AND CloseDate = THIS_YEAR AND StageName = 'Closed Won'];
        for(Opportunity oppty : opptyList){
            if(!acctIdOpptyListMap.containsKey(oppty.AccountId)){
                acctIdOpptyListMap.put(oppty.AccountId, new List<Opportunity>());
            }
            acctIdOpptyListMap.get(oppty.AccountId).add(oppty); 
        }   
        List<Account> acctList = new List<Account>();
        acctList = [SELECT This_year_income__c FROM Account WHERE Id IN: acctIds];
        for(Account acct : acctList){
            List<Opportunity> tempOpptyList = new List<Opportunity>();
            tempOpptyList = acctIdOpptyListMap.get(acct.Id);
            Double totalOpptyAmount = 0;
            for(Opportunity oppty : tempOpptyList){
                if(oppty.Amount != null){
                    totalOpptyAmount += oppty.Amount;
                }
            }
            acct.This_year_income__c = totalOpptyAmount;
        }
        update acctList;
    }
}
```

And now, splitted:
Trigger

```
trigger OpportunityTrigger on Opportunity (after insert, after update, after delete) {
    
    OpportunityHandler oppHandler = new OpportunityHandler();
    
    if (Trigger.isAfter && (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate)){
        oppHandler.handlerAfterUpdateOrInsert(Trigger.new);
    }

    if (Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isDelete){
        oppHandler.handlerAfterDelete(Trigger.old);
    }
}
```

And Handler:

```
public with sharing class OpportunityHandler {
    Map<Id, List<Opportunity>> acctIdOpptyListMap = new Map<Id, List<Opportunity>>();
    Set<Id> acctIds = new Set<Id>();
    List<Opportunity> opptyList = new List<Opportunity>();
    public void handlerAfterUpdateOrInsert(List<Opportunity> oppList) {
        for(Opportunity oppty : oppList){
            if(oppty.AccountId != null){
                acctIds.add(oppty.AccountId);
            }
        }    
    }

    public void handlerAfterDelete(List<Opportunity> opsList){
        for(Opportunity oppty : opsList){
            if(oppty.AccountId != null){
                acctIds.add(oppty.AccountId);
            }
        }
    }
    if(acctIds.size() > 0){
        opptyList = [SELECT Amount, AccountId FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId IN : acctIds AND CloseDate = THIS_YEAR AND StageName = 'Closed Won'];
        for(Opportunity oppty : opptyList){
            if(!acctIdOpptyListMap.containsKey(oppty.AccountId)){
                acctIdOpptyListMap.put(oppty.AccountId, new List<Opportunity>());
            }
            acctIdOpptyListMap.get(oppty.AccountId).add(oppty); 
        }   
        List<Account> acctList = new List<Account>();
        acctList = [SELECT This_year_income__c FROM Account WHERE Id IN: acctIds];
        for(Account acct : acctList){
            List<Opportunity> tempOpptyList = new List<Opportunity>();
            tempOpptyList = acctIdOpptyListMap.get(acct.Id);
            Double totalOpptyAmount = 0;
            for(Opportunity oppty : tempOpptyList){
                if(oppty.Amount != null){
                    totalOpptyAmount += oppty.Amount;
                }
            }
            acct.This_year_income__c = totalOpptyAmount;
        }
        update acctList;
    }
}
```

**FIXED**
I am getting

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void handlerAfterDelete(List) from the type OpportunityHandler

**Ramaining issue**
Also don't know what's the best way to actually connect the code in the handler, from  `if(acctIds.size() > 0){...` could this be a separated part of code or should this logic be included under if (trigger...) condition

Thank you for any input on this.

Comment: You are trying to call a non-static method in a static manner.

Comment: @PhilW Are you going to be turning this into an answer?

Comment: @PhilW thank you, I am stupid, fixed that part. 

`OpportunityHandler oppHandler = new OpportunityHandler();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue, as PhilW pointed out, is that you're mixing up how static and non-static (also called "instance") methods are called.

A static method is one that uses the `static` keyword in the method signature.

```
public class MyClass{
    public static void myStaticMethod(){
    }
}
```

and you call it using the name of the class and the method
`MyClass.myStaticMethod()`

If you're not using the `static` keyword, then you need to create an instance of your class, and call the method from that instance.

```java
public class MyClass{
    public void myInstanceMethod(){
    }
}

// The "new" operator causes us to create a new instance of a class (and run
//   the appropriate constructor)
MyClass myClassInstance = new MyClass();

// Instance methods are called on instances of the given class
myClassInstance.myInstanceMethod();
```

In the end, it doesn't really matter which way you end up going. I will say that making your `OpportunityHandler` methods static would be the least amount of work and follows the general pattern for trigger handlers (there's not much reason to make and use instances of your handler class).

As for how to handle the rest of the code from your trigger, consider that the code in question is being run in *all of your trigger contexts* (insert, update, and delete). The only bits that are different depending on whether it's an insert, update, or delete is in gathering the account Ids that feed the main part of your logic.

Code that's used multiple times is code that should become a method.

Also notice how now that you're not using `trigger.new` and `trigger.old` directly, your 2 existing `handler*` methods are exactly the same. You could roll everything into a single method, but having separate methods for each trigger context is what most trigger frameworks do (and it helps your code's flexibility).

I'd suggest something like the following

```java
trigger OpportunityTrigger on Opportunity (before insert, after insert, before update, after update, before delete, after delete, after undelete) {
    // Even if you're not using all of these events, adding them here and now
    //   means you won't have to update this trigger later if you decide to add
    //   additional work for Opportunities
    switch on trigger.OperationType{
        when TriggerOperation.BEFORE_INSERT { OpportunityHandler.onBeforeInsert(trigger.new); }
        when TriggerOperation.AFTER_INSERT { OpportunityHandler.onAfterInsert(trigger.new); }
        when TriggerOperation.BEFORE_UPDATE { OpportunityHandler.onBeforeUpdate(trigger.old, trigger.new); }
        when TriggerOperation.AFTER_UPDATE { OpportunityHandler.onAfterUpdate(trigger.old, trigger.new); }
        when TriggerOperation.BEFORE_DELETE { OpportunityHandler.onBeforeDelete(trigger.old); }
        when TriggerOperation.AFTER_DELETE { OpportunityHandler.onAfterDelete(trigger.old); }
        when TriggerOperation.AFTER_UNDELETE { OpportunityHandler.onAfterUndelete(trigger.new); }
    }
}
```

```java
public with sharing class OpportunityHandler {
    // Static methods can only access static class variables, so make these static too
    static Map<Id, List<Opportunity>> acctIdOpptyListMap = new Map<Id, List<Opportunity>>();
    static Set<Id> acctIds = new Set<Id>();

    // If there's a trigger context you're not doing anything with, it's ok to just
    //   leave the event handling method blank
    public static void onBeforeInsert(List<Opportunity> oppList){
    }

    public static void onAfterInsert(List<Opportunity> oppList){
        // You could process oppList here, then call the method that does the actual work
        //   but that'd mean you're repeating code several times.
        // Common code usually means that it should be part of a method

        // The responsibility of each handler method is to tell us in simple terms
        //   what work we want to do (and in what order, if you end up
        //   doing more work on Opportunities sometime down the line)
        updateAccountAmount(oppList);
    }

    public static void onBeforeUpdate(List<Opportunity> oldOppList, List<Opportunity> newOppList){
    }

    public static void onAfterUpdate(List<Opportunity> oldOppList, List<Opportunity> newOppList){
        updateAccountAmount(oppList);
    }

    public static void onBeforeDelete(List<Opportunity> oppList){
    }

    public static void onAfterDelete(List<Opportunity> oppList){
        updateAccountAmount(oppList);
    }

    public static void onAfterUndelete(List<Opportunity> oppList){
    }

    private static void updateAccountAmount(List<opportunity> givenOpps){
        // Now that you're not using trigger context variables directly, you can simply
        // use givenOpps
        for(Opportunity opp :givenOpps){
            acctIds.add(opp.AccountId);
        }

        // Since you're using a set, you don't need to check if something is null
        //   in the loop.
        // We can just remove null outside of the loop.
        // Either approach works.
        acctIds.remove(null);

        // Instead of wrapping everything inside an if(acctIds.size() > 0), I generally
        //   prefer to keep most of the code outside of the if().
        // We can simply return early if there are no account ids
        if(acctIds.isEmpty()){
            return;
        }

        /*
            The rest of the code (that's currently inside your main if() block
            goes here
        */
    }
}
```

With this approach, the `acctIds` set and your `acctIdOpptyListMap` could be made local variables in `updateAccountAmount()` instead of being static class variables, but either way would work.

There are improvements that could be made (you could eliminate most of the code if you used a query on Opportunity to sum the amount data for you and `GROUP BY AccountId`), but perhaps that's something to focus on once you get a bit more familiar with Apex.

Answer (score 1):

Your trigger is invoking the handler method like:

```
OpportunityHandler.handlerAfterDelete(Trigger.old);
```

This is fine when the `handlerAfterDelete` method is static, but it is not. You should ensure you instantiate the handler, perhaps like:

```
trigger OpportunityTrigger on Opportunity (after insert, after update, after delete) {
    OpportunityHandler handler = new OpportunityHandler();

    if (Trigger.isAfter && (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate)){
        handler.handlerAfterUpdateOrInsert(Trigger.new);
    }

    if (Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isDelete){
        handler.handlerAfterDelete(Trigger.old);
    }
}
```

Of course, there are many other ways you could do this. You might even want to consider allowing for dependency injection via the use of an abstract factory or similar. Have a look at [this Joy of Apex](https://www.jamessimone.net/blog/joys-of-apex/dependency-injection-factory-pattern/) discussion on that topic.

**UPDATE**:

In response to @DerekF's excellent answer, I would say that we actually have handlers that are instantiated (via dependency injection) in triggers, avoiding static logic.

We do this specifically to enable better testing - we don't actually change the implementation at production runtime.

By doing this we are able to:

- Simply turn off trigger handling with a trivial no-op implementation (e.g. to insert "bad data" to simulate upgrade scenarios).
- Mock out or augment the handlers to allow simulation of errors caused by external sources (e.g. subscriber added triggers, validation rules, record-triggered flows etc.).

Of course, you could even make use of this in certain production scenarios as well.